# September 2023 photo contest: on the water

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

I’m cocomac, and I'll be running the photo contest for September.

**The topic is "on the water"**, meaning anything that’s on the water, including (but not limited to) buoys, boats, wildlife, etc.

Standard rules apply (explicitly, it’s the same rules as the last photo contest).

Note that I was unfortunately unable to post this at the exact start time, so **do not post photos until the start of September (UTC time)**. The contest ends at the end of September, and it will use UTC time.

---

This photo contest has concluded, congratulations to Tetsujin for winning! I've also [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20231001005647/https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/september-2023-photo-contest-on-the-water) this post (although I did also check the actual +/- scores).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Heron - a time to reflect**
Occasional visitor to a park in North London

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Flamingos in Laguna Colorada, Bolivia

April 2019

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Glacial iceberg, Tracy Arm Alaska.

[image]

Photo taken by me, August 31, 2023

Answer (score 6):

Rainbow over the Pacific ocean.  Photo taken on Oahu, near Ewa Beach, facing south into the peaceful Spring of 2021.

[image: Ewa Beach Rainbow]

Answer (score 6):

Indigenous boat on the Amazon River, Pará, Brazil

November 2017

[image: 1]

Comment: Congratulations - you win the virtual prize this month!

Answer (score 4):

Ok so I'll go first! :)

This was at the end of July this year in [Izola, Slovenia](https://maps.app.goo.gl/4EX9VNR76NWXNCME7).

[image: cargo ships]

I've visited four continents at least once so far and I've seen cargo ships of this company everywhere. So, when I noticed them on my walk from Koper to Izola, I wanted to take a pic from the closest point along the coast.

Answer (score 3):

Sunrise on the harbour, Tauranga New Zealand.  Photo taken by me November 2016, a week before we left NZ and moved to Mexico

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**"Three Men in a Boat"**

Taken by me today on the River Great Ouse in East Anglia, UK.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

River vendor, Chao Phraya River, Bangkok Thailand.  Photo taken by me August 1992

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be offtopic since they are somehow *over* the water but...kitesurfers at [Playa de Valdevaqueros](https://maps.app.goo.gl/5oSMozmfARZLeGj27), near Tarifa (Spain) on July 4th, 2022. Own pictures. What a beautiful walk was that, from [Tarifa](https://maps.app.goo.gl/ZPnPa3z5qNyRX4GL8) to [the dune](https://maps.app.goo.gl/nc8VxWVyKZKWDBaH8) and back!!

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]